# Show only letters from usernames in database

Tags: php, database

I think this is really simple, but I can't get my head around it.

I would like to achieve something like this:
Get all names from database.
Get first letter for each name.
Show all 26 Alphabet characters + numbers:
A B C D E F etc...0-9

And only put a link on the characters, which are the first letter of a username. In other words something like this:

Usernames from database-> Moonwalker, Tester, Admin, Tutorial, Arial

All characters are visible:

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S
>   T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but only the letters that have the same first letter as usernames are linked to something:

> [A](http://#) B C D E F G H I J K L [M](http://#) N O P Q R S
>   [T](http://#) U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I know it's possible, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can get the first letter:

```
SELECT LEFT(`name`, 1) AS first_letter
  FROM users
```

This is how you can find users using first letter (with first `B`):

```
SELECT `name`
  FROM users
 WHERE `name` LIKE 'B%'
```

This is how you can get the list of first letters, that exist in database (with optional count of occurrences):

```
  SELECT LEFT(`name`, 1) AS first_letter,
         COUNT(*) AS occurrences
    FROM users
GROUP BY first_letter
```

Comment: @Russell Dias: thanks, cannot remember how to write it properly :-(

Answer (score 1):

I would rather grab all necessary users from DB and group them by first letter in PHP.
Here u can find something similar : http://php.bigresource.com/Track/php-A1gPapjn/

If you need fully working code just let me know. In a meanwhile I can prepare some example.

--
Regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks Robert. I know how to get only the first letters of users in the database, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it like I explained above. It's just something I'm trying to figure out for myself, because it looks kind of cool. :)

Thanks again for the link.